# How would multiple minds control a single body?

Tags: science-based, humans, mind

One trope seen in movies is mind control. This trope involves a person or thing taking over another person’s body, whilst visual or auditory cues and friends try to help the original person regain their body’s control.

This trope, however, gave me a thought.  How could multiple minds control a single body? Whenever we see such a thing portrayed in shows, we usually see the person usually switch in between one person or the other, and this will sometimes result in the person causing self harm in themselves.

But this leads me to my question.

**If all of the minds and consciousness of humanity were to be suddenly placed into a single body, what would be the catastrophic fall out?**

Comment: Have you seen video games played on Twitch? Same thing. :-)

Comment: @SRM That's..... Actually far more relevant than I may have first thought.

Comment: @SRM: If twitch is the standard we’re going by then the answer to this question is ‘poorly’!

Answer (score 5):

If one body housed the entire consciousness of humanity, then the other bodies would die, either starving to death or dying of thirst or by misadventure when they lost control over their original body and fell into a garbage disposal, crashed their car, plane, rocket-ship, etc.

Assuming all minds had equal control over the body, I suspect that body would very quickly tear tendons, break some bones, and sprain, or worse, muscle tissue as each mind reacted to suddenly being somewhere else, being suddenly taller or shorter or thinner or fatter or younger or old enough to finally buy beer.

Given the percentage of people that lose their composure at the slightest disturbance, I think the body would scream itself unconsciousness.  I’ve seen it and its not pretty.

Assuming when the body wakes up, those minds have gone into a form of catalepsy and are inactive.  Then, I think the rest of the minds are going to start asking what is going on or what is happening.  But, they’ll be doing it at the same time and in different languages.

My guess is that the minds will only succeed in biting their tongue off, then drowning in their own blood.

But, assuming the body lives, and the minds find some way to communicate and share the body, then they’ll first seek food, water, and shelter while the body recovers from its assorted sprains, pulls, and broken bones before they are eaten by feral cats.

Answer (score 4):

The human brain has lots of unknowns, but one thing we have clear is that many neurons follow the plan of “fire when it’s neighbors collectively supply sufficient stimulus (add up the stimulus)”, with some neighbors able to add a negative stimulus (inhibition).

Let’s assume this consensus pattern holds when multiple minds are in control... the body will act when the majority of minds try to perform a given action.

That means autonomic systems should keep running ... our brains will all encourage heartbeat, breathing, etc, though there may be some problems if the particular body is not near the human mean. So if average human has lungs and draws X times per minute, but our new body is used to much less oxygen than that average, we might hyperventilate. But we will probably get that under control.

The next challenge will be the conscious movements. Have you ever seen the website Twitch? Collectively, people try to play games by all making moves and the system plays the consensus move. It’s a mess: fun to watch sometimes. Our body will be a lot like that. Do the minds have the ability to talk to each other? If not, it’ll be very hard to coordinate activities. If yes, it’ll be very hard to coordinate activities, but it’ll get better over time. :-) You have to decide which minds can talk to which other minds or if everyone talks on a single common channel, requiring politeness of letting others talk. If it is a single channel, the human race is probably doomed because some idiot will think it is funny to yell into the channel constantly... probably millions of idiots out of humanity’s billions.

But assuming they can meaningfully communicate, and assuming they all can see through the eyes simultaneously, eventually a plurality will decide to work together and will start blocking out the contradictory actions of the others.

Eventually the minority will find themselves literally prisoners in their own minds, unable to act because they are never in the majority.

Now the big question for you: if all humanity is in one body, who the hell are we going to breed with? It’s going to be a brief species if we don’t have a sizable population!

Comment: "Collectively, people try to play games by all making moves and the system plays the consensus move." One linky, please, just one.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitch_Plays_Pokémon  This is the original inspiration. Twitch has expanded to other games and other models of play since then.

Answer (score 2):

Without a working theory of mind (think "artificial intelligence"), we can only speculate on how this would work. But there may be an analogy that is worth considering...

Imagine a modern computer network consisting of many workstations. At two (or more) of these workstations there are people sitting down, and they are antagonists with regards to each other. They wish to use the computer's automation systems to control various physical things... opening the garage doors, lowering or raising the thermostats, etc.

In a normal system like the one in my hypothetical, permissions for such actions are carefully curated, likely only one or the other can change any of these. But all are knowledgeable about how the these systems work, and wish to perform the actions even if their nominal authority does not allow for such.

It is plausible that one or the other can lock their opponent out of the system (temporarily or permanently) just by being the first to seize control. It is also plausible that in some or all cases, they cannot lock each other out... and when one performs an action, the other can immediately attempt to reverse it.

And which scenario would win out is really down to the details of the system. The software and network architecture (does the human nervous system have a security architecture?). While the sophistication of the opponents does matter, in your more general scenario we can't assume that one human mind is better at seizing control of a human body than another.

We don't know the architecture of the human nervous system well enough to tell which is which. There is the natural phenomenon of dissociative identity disorder which parallels this, but it's unclear if that only presents as multiple minds in a single body or is truly such a thing.